# NLTK corpora download is hanging when run in AWS Lambda Python function

Tags: python, lambda, nltk

I'm trying to download NLTK data onto the file storage of a Lambda function like so:

```
nltk.data.path.append("/tmp")
nltk.download("popular", download_dir="/tmp")
```

The Lambda function keeps timing out. When I check the Cloudwatch logs, I see no logs related to the download of different corpora files (e.g. `Downloading package cmudict to /tmp...`; instead the code seems to reach up to `nltk.download()`, then hang forever.

Has anyone seen this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Got it: My Lambda function was running in a VPC. I had to add an endpoint to enable the VPC to access S3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).